# How can I uninstall a startup item in MacOS x

Tags: osx-leopard

I have setup my MacOSX environment to run a script 'Emacs Daemon.app' under /Application/Emacs Daemon.app'.  But now I want to uninstall that. i.e. I do not want Emacs Daemon.app run every time I log in. But I forget how I setup my Mac OSX environment to run that program.

Can anyone please let me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove it from your login items in the Accounts>user>Login Items preference pane, otherwise check for it in ~/Library/LaunchAgents